# Why does the gettype() say it's a double but var_dump() says float?

Tags: php, gettype, var-dump

Why does the gettype() say it's a double but var_dump() says float?

```
$number = 1234567890123456789;
echo "Number: {$number} is a ". gettype($number) . "\n";
var_dump($number);
```

Response:

> Number: 1.23456789012E+18 is a double 
>   float(1.23456789012E+18)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They're the same thing http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Comment: thats a problem in my case

Answer (score 7):

Directly from PHP.net ([gettype()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php)):

> Possibles values for the returned string are:
>
> ...
>   *"double" (for historical reasons "double" is returned in case of a float, and not simply "float")* ...

Answer (score 1):

```
<br>
<?php 
        /*begins with a function that runs a Console msg for PHP */
function console_sn($txt){
$temp = "";
$temp .= "<script>";
$temp .= "console.info('frm_PHP: '+'";
$temp .= $txt;
$temp .= "');";
$temp .= "</script>";
echo $temp;
}
echo("<br><hr><br>");
//end of PHP console function

//Main primary code for this Example begins below

//run these examples below in your test PHP file and see the results in your JS console window

//e.g.#1
$code1 = "1212";
console_sn(gettype(floatval($code1)));

//e.g.#2
$code2 = "1212sn";
console_sn(gettype(floatval($code2)));

//e.g.#3
$code3 = "1212";
console_sn(gettype((trim($code3))*1));

//e.g.#4
$code4 = "1212sn";
console_sn(gettype((trim($code4))*1));

?>
```

Comment: Copy and Paste this code block above into your PHP test file and see the results appear in your Javascript _**Console**_ window.